# Javascript regexp: Using variables in backreference pattern?

Tags: javascript, regex, backreference

I've got a pattern to find matches in a querystring:

```
'url.com/foo/bar?this=that&thing=another'.replace(/(thing=)([^&]*)/, '$1test')
```

What I'd like to be able to do is use variable values as the param to match like:

```
'url.com/foo/bar?this=that&thing=another'.replace('/(' + key + '=)([^&]*)/', '$1test')
```

[edit] Here's the context in how the code is being used:

```
GetSrcParam: function(key, value) {
            var newSrc = $(this._image).attr('src'),
                pattern = '(' + key + '=)([^&]*)';

            if (newSrc.match(pattern) == null)
                newSrc += '&' + key + '=' + value;
            else
                newSrc = newSrc.replace(newSrc, '$1' + value);

            return newSrc;
        }
```

But it's not working as intended - can anyone help?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please use code formattng (you only have to push a button). - Also please provide some JS code, not just the patterns themselves. The problem probably ies in how you prepare your pattern.

Comment: Apologies, didn't notice it - have updated with context in which the js is being (or would like to be) used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you choose to construct a regex from a string, you need to drop the delimiters (but then you need to double any backslashes, if your regex were to contain any). Try

```
myregex = new RegExp('(' + key + '=)([^&]*)')
'url.com/foo/bar?this=that&thing=another'.replace(myregex, '$1test')
```

Are you aware that this would also match `thing=another` in `url.com/foo/bar?something=another`? To avoid this, add a word boundary anchor:

```
myregex = new RegExp('(\\b' + key + '=)([^&]*)')
```